# Caesar Cipher Python Inquiry

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, caesar-cipher

I've recently started learning about python.
Upon studying the Caesar's Cipher, I ran into this trouble:

(Here is the code I've worked on so far)

```
plain_text = 'PYTHON'

cipher_text = ''

alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

key = 2

for i in range(len(plain_text)):

    symbol = plain_text[i]
    for i in range(len(alphabet)):
        if symbol == alphabet[i]:
            new_symbol = alphabet[i + key]
            cipher_text = cipher_text + new_symbol

print(cipher_text)
```

The string is out of range in line `new_symbol = alphabet[i + key]`. I am aware that this is probably because shifted spot of Y and Z does not exist. However, I cannot figure out how to loop(?) the alphabets so that this error does not happen. (From ABC...Z to ABC...ZABC...ZABC...Z)

Comment: Modular arithmetic: `alphabet[(i + key) % len(alphabet)]`

Comment: Damn works fine man. Thanks so much <3